# Want to generate graph using perfmon plugin in Jmeter?

Tags: ant, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

As per project requirement i am using JMeter as Loadtesting tool. JMeterPlugin available on http://jmeter-plugins.org really leverages your overall load testing results. I am using perfmon plugin and capture CPU,Memory, Disk IO and Network IO (this internally uses SIGAR framwrok). That works fine in UI Mode, but while i launched Jmeter using ANT in non gui mode, it's able to generate graphs specific to Jmeter (Response time,TPS, etc) but not able to generate System matrices which i included in test plan. did any one has tried this Plugin in Non GUI mode?

Please find below snippet of build.xml

```
<target name="create-graphs" depends="create-reports">
        <ac:for param="reportType" list="AggregateReport,HitsPerSecond,ResponseTimesPercentiles,ThroughputOverTime,ThroughputVsThreads,TimesVsThreads,ResponseTimesOverTime,ThreadsStateOverTime,TransactionsPerSecond">
            <sequential>
                <java jar="${jmeter.home}/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar" fork="true">
                    <arg value="--tool"/>
                    <arg value="Reporter"/>
                    <arg value="--generate-png"/>
                    <arg value="${result.path}/@{reportType}.png"/>
                    <arg value="--input-jtl"/>
                    <arg value="${result.path}/JMeterResults.xml"/>
                    <arg value="--plugin-type"/>
                    <arg value="@{reportType}"/>
                    <arg value="--width"/>
                    <arg value="800"/>
                    <arg value="--height"/>
                    <arg value="600"/>
                </java>
            </sequential>
        </ac:for>
    </target>
```

Thanks,

Priyank Shah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Servers Performance Monitoring listener saves results in its own separate result file, not the common result file. So you should use this separate file for reporting.